# Why is my conforming dictionary not getting turned into a table?

Tags: kdb

Let's say I have a table:

```
m:([] t: raze 3#'(2021.01.04+til 5); sym:15#`A`B`C; c: til 15)

t          sym c
-----------------
2021.01.04 A   0
2021.01.04 B   1
2021.01.04 C   2
2021.01.05 A   3
2021.01.05 B   4
```

When I try to pivot it:

```
exec t!c by sym:sym from m

sym|
---| -----------------------------------------------------------------
A  | 2021.01.04 2021.01.05 2021.01.06 2021.01.07 2021.01.08!0 3 6 9 12
B  | 2021.01.04 2021.01.05 2021.01.06 2021.01.07 2021.01.08!1 4 7 10 13
C  | 2021.01.04 2021.01.05 2021.01.06 2021.01.07 2021.01.08!2 5 8 11 14
```

I'd expect to get a table back, with columns `sym`, but I don't. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you're after a pivot with columns of `sym` you would want the following:

```
q)exec sym!c by t:t from m
t         | A  B  C
----------| --------
2021.01.04| 0  1  2
2021.01.05| 3  4  5
2021.01.06| 6  7  8
2021.01.07| 9  10 11
2021.01.08| 12 13 14
```

Answer (score 3):

It's because your column names have to be symbols:

```
q)exec(`$string t)!c by sym:sym from m
sym| 2021.01.04 2021.01.05 2021.01.06 2021.01.07 2021.01.08
---| ------------------------------------------------------
A  | 0          3          6          9          12
B  | 1          4          7          10         13
C  | 2          5          8          11         14
```

These would be terrible column names though, so I would use `.Q.id`

```
q).Q.id exec(`$string t)!c by sym:sym from m
sym| a20210104 a20210105 a20210106 a20210107 a20210108
---| -------------------------------------------------
A  | 0         3         6         9         12
B  | 1         4         7         10        13
C  | 2         5         8         11        14
```

It sounds like this isn't what you actually want though, so maybe Matthews answer is more relevant. My answer just explains why it didn't look like what you thought